# Biblatex Sorting Bibliography by author and afterwards numbering it by appearence in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm using `biblatex` to create a bibliography with two parts, one part for literature and one part for internet sources. Now I want to sort each bibliography by NTY. Afterwards the entries in the bibliography should be numbered from top to bottom. This should happen in both bibliographies and I want the first number of the second bibliography to be the following of the last of the first bibliography.

I don't think a MWE would make sense because I don't even have a beginning of the problem.

Comment: How would you like to specify which of the entries goes into the first and which goes into the second bibliography? (Just by entry type?) Do you already have the two part bibliography, or is obtaining that also a part of your question? Do you use the `numeric` style of `biblatex`? Really, an MWE of even the barest kind of set-up you already have could help us.

Comment: Bibs are already split into two parts by using the code you also mentioned.
I inserted \DeclarePresort[online]{zzzzzzzzzzzzz} but it didnt work.

Comment: Did you try my code snipped on your computer though? You will need to use Biber.

Comment: are there any disadvanteges using biber with biblatex and texmaker ?

Comment: Is there a posibility to get it to work without using biber ?

Comment: You should be able to use Biber with texmaker (see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)). I don't think you can customise sorting a great deal with bibtex(8), my solution certainly depends on using biber (`\DeclarePresort` is biber only). Biber is the recommended backend now anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to split `@online` and all other types into two bibliographies, that is as easy as

```
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\printbibliography[type=online]
```

The first command prints all entries save for those of type `@online`, while the latter prints only `@online` entries.

We then use `defernumbers=true`, this options makes sure "numeric labels (i.e., the `labelnumber` field [...]) are assigned the first time an entry is printed in any bibliography" (p. 52, §3.1.1 *Load-time Options*/`defernumbers` of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

`nty` sorting is obtained by

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=nty,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=nty,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{baez/online,cicero,wassenberg,wilde}
  \printbibliography[nottype=online]
  \printbibliography[type=online]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For more on `defernumbers` see [biblatex - Consistent numbering in split bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864) and [biblatex advises defernumbers=true but details of references may be very hard to find](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332431/35864)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which works with `biblatex` independent of the backend used. Since the OP asked about using `bibtex`, my example specifies this, but nothing depends on it. `backend=biber` would work at least as well.

This answer is based on moewe's solution. I ran that code and read the output. `biblatex` suggested the `defernumbers` option there. Looking in the documentation, I learnt that `defernumbers`, unlike `\DeclarePresort` is not specific to `biber`. An added (but extremely minor) bonus is that it gets rid of the warning from `biblatex` on compilation.

In general, `biblatex` assigns numbers to reference entries at the beginning of the document. If `defernumbers` is set to `true`, however, it does not assign numbers until they are first used in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sorting=nty,defernumbers=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{baez/online,cicero,wassenberg,wilde}
  \printbibliography[nottype=online]
  \printbibliography[type=online]
\end{document}
```

[image: References with deferred numbering]

Note that the documentation warns that you need two runs of `latex` to get the numbering right, over and above the runs needed to get pagination etc. correct. Moreover, should you change the value of `defernumbers`, you will probably need to delete the `.aux` file. (Though I didn't find I needed to do this going from the default `false` setting to `true`.)