# biblatex - Consistent numbering in split bibliographies

Tags: biblatex

I have a document in which the bibliography is splitted via categories. I would like to reference to the elements by numbers [1]. Inside each bibliography, the entries should be sorted by year-name-title (ynt), but the numbers in the first bibliography should be smaller than the numbers in the second one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting = ynt,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{a,
        author = "I",
        year = "1973"
    }
    @book{a2,
        author = "I",
        year = "1923"
    }
    @book{b,
        author = "You",
        year = "1959"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{own}

\begin{document}

\nocite{a,a2}
\addtocategory{own}{a,a2}
\nocite{b}

\printbibliography[category=own,title={A}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=own,title={B}]

\end{document}
```

Now, the order of the numbers in the bibliography is "[1],[3]" in the first list, and "[2]" in the second list. This looks odd and if there are more items, one has to search through both lists in order to find a reference. I would like to have "[1],[2]" in the first list and "[3]" in the second list.

An option is to add a "presort" key to the corresponding entries in the bib-file, but I would like to *not* touch the bib-file. Is there, e.g., any possibility to add the "presort" key afterwards in the tex-file? Or can biblatex sort by category (I searched the manual but did not found any clue)?

Comment: It might be cheating, but what about using `defernumbers=true`? This is even `biblatex`'s recommendation as you can see in the `.log` file: `Package biblatex Warning: Setting 'defernumbers=true' recommended.`

Comment: Rather than cheating, this looks like the intended solution. The manual says (§3.12.5) "When using a numeric citation scheme, however,
this will most likely lead to discontinuous numbering in split bibliographies. Use the defernumbers package option to avoid this problem." Please post it as an answer.

Comment: When I said cheating, I was referring to the fact that we weren't actually sorting by the `category` which is, I think, not possible out of the box (AFAIK Biber does not get to see the categories). So I was at least cheating in answering the title question.

Comment: But, it was not my main concern to get the entries sorted via the category, but to get a consistent numbering. So you answered the question I intended to ask ;) I will change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow `biblatex`'s advice in the `.log` file

```
Package biblatex Warning: Split bibliography detected.
(biblatex)                Many simple split bibliography setups with
(biblatex)                non-overlapping bibliographies benefit from
(biblatex)                setting 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                See the documentation for details.
(biblatex)                This warning can be suppressed with
(biblatex)                '\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff'.
```

and use `defernumbers=true`.

*edit*: This message was removed from a few versions following discussions in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/493, but it is back now.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains on p. 53

> In contrast to standard LaTeX, the numeric labels generated by this
> package are normally assigned to the full list of references at the
> beginning of the document body. If this option is enabled, numeric
> labels [...] are assigned the first time an entry is printed in any
> bibliography.

and notes in §3.12.5 Bibliography Filters and Citation Labels, p. 121, that

> The citation labels generated by this package are assigned to the full
> list of references before it is split up by any bibliography filters.
> They are guaranteed to be unique across the entire document (or a
> `refsection` environment), no matter how many bibliography filters you
> are using. When using a numeric citation scheme, however, this will
> most likely lead to discontinuous numbering in split bibliographies.
> Use the `defernumbers` package option to avoid this problem. If this
> option is enabled, numeric labels are assigned the first time an entry
> is printed in any bibliography.