# biblatex - Sort cites via number (split bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

This is a follow-up question to [biblatex - Consistent numbering in split bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271751/biblatex-consistent-numbering-in-split-bibliographies).

My bibliography is split into two parts via categories. The entries are numbered consecutively and I want to sort the entries within each `\cite`. However, inside each `\cite` the entries are ordered (first) by year and, thus, entries of the first and second part of the bibliography get mixed up.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    sorting      = ynt,
    bibstyle     = numeric,
    defernumbers = true,
    sortcites    = true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{a,
        author = "I",
        year = "1973"
    }
    @book{a2,
        author = "I",
        year = "1923"
    }
    @book{b,
        author = "You",
        year = "1959"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{own}

\begin{document}

\cite{a,a2,b}

\addtocategory{own}{a,a2}

\printbibliography[category=own,title={A}]
\printbibliography[notcategory=own,title={B}]

\end{document}
```

The cite reads `[1, 3, 2]` but I would like to have `[1, 2, 3]`.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Now you see why I said I cheated before. For proper sorting as in the former title of the other question we need a bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want to sort entries with a certain property before other entries and sorting is done by Biber we will have to tell Biber in the `.bib` which entry has this property (there is a way to get out of this limitation, see below for more details).

So we cannot use bibcategories any more, we will use `keywords` instead.
Just add `keywords = {own}` to the relevant entries

```
@book{a,
  author = "I",
  year = "1973",
  keywords = {own},
}
```

Naturally the bibliographies are filtered with `keyword` and `notkeyword` now

```
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={A}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own,title={B}]
```

We then check for `own` and, if the keyword is present, fill the `presort` field with `A`, otherwise it gets a `B`.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{(^|,)own(,|$)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {A}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {B}]
    }
  }
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    sorting      = ynt,
    bibstyle     = numeric,
    defernumbers = true,
    sortcites    = true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author = "I",
  year = "1973",
  keywords = {own},
}
@book{a2,
  author = "I",
  year = "1923",
  keywords = {own},
}
@book{b,
  author = "You",
  year = "1959",
}
@book{c,
  author = "You",
  year = "1970",
  keywords = {notmine},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match=\regexp{(^|,)own(,|$)}, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {A}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {B}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,a2,b,c}

\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={A}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own,title={B}]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

To do everything from within your `.tex` file use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{^(a|a2)$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {A}]
    }
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{^(a|a2)$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue = {own}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {B}]
    }
  }
}
```

Where you replace `(a|a2)` in the two steps above with a list of "own" entry keys separated by `|`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    sorting      = ynt,
    bibstyle     = numeric,
    defernumbers = true,
    sortcites    = true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author = "I",
  year = "1973",
}
@book{a2,
  author = "I",
  year = "1923",
}
@book{b,
  author = "You",
  year = "1959",
}
@book{c,
  author = "You",
  year = "1970",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{^(a|a2)$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {A}]
    }
    \map[overwrite=true]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{^(a|a2)$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue = {own}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=presort, fieldvalue = {B}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{a,a2,b,c}

\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={A}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own,title={B}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I use the same bib-file across multiple projects, I refrain from modifying the bib-file. Is there any possibility to fill the `presort`-field in the tex-file by, e.g., using the category or by a `\customCommand{a2}`?

Comment: @gerw Scrap my earlier comment, I found a solution, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used and modified your approach to provide a `\citeown`-command, which adds references to the regexp in the sourcemap.