# BibLatex: right reference order in multiple bibliography lists and wrong reference order in cite

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have several bibliography lists with ynt sorting order each. When I cite references from the list I need [1-4] sorting instead of [1,3,2,4].

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true, sorting=ynt,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
    @article{Author01,
        author = "Author A",
        title = "Article A",
        journal="J1",
        year = "2001"
     }
    @article{Author02,
        author = "Author B",
        title = "Article B",
        journal="J1",
        year = "2002"
    }
    @article{Author03,
        author = "Author C",
        title = "Article C",
        journal="J1",
        year = "2003"
    }
    @article{Author04,
        author = "Author D",
        title = "Article D",
        journal="J1",
        year = "2004"
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{A}
\addtocategory{A}{Author01,Author03}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{B}
\addtocategory{B}{Author02,Author04}

\begin{document}
    I introduce citations from the bib file \cite{Author01,Author03,Author02,Author04} 
and it doesn't write [1--4].

    \printbibliography[category=A,title={List A}]
    \printbibliography[category=B,title={List B}]   
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Lists are ok for me, the trouble is with the order of references in cite command.

Comment: As I can see in the related topics (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273313/biblatex-sort-cites-via-number-split-bibliography?rq=1) the solution is in using keywords. I use mendeley and my bib file is being formed automatically. Is there any solution for mendeley or for categories?

Comment: Hmm.. What a fool I am. I was a bit confused that the field keywords in Mendeley is for author keywords. But I can use it on my own as well. I solved the issue with the help of the solution in the linked topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used solution from [biblatex - Sort cites via number (split bibliography)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273313/biblatex-sort-cites-via-number-split-bibliography?rq=1) using keywords. Since my bib file is being formed automatically by Mendeley, I used the field "Author Keywords" to tag necessary references. Cite ordering is ok now.