# Biblatex - bibliography sectioning and numbered list of references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sectioning

I am using Biblatex and sectioning my references into two different sections like this:

```
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[type=misc,title={Miscellanous}]
```

This works fine, except for the fact that the book section is not numbered the way I want it, I want it to start with '1' and then the next ones '2', '3',...
This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably want the options `sorting=none` and/or `defernumbers=true`. If this is not enough, please consider adding a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to your question with specifics on how *both* your bibliographies should be numbered.

Comment: I'd say you want `defernumbers=true`. If you try this and don't get the expected results immediately, delete the temporary files and recompile from scratch.

Comment: Any news here? In order to give a proper answer we need to know more about your document than just a blurred screenshot and two lines of code. If any of the comments helped a heads-up would be appreciated.

Comment: Any news here? At the moment this seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864, a short heads-up would be appreciated.

Comment: I voted to close because there was no response to the suggested ideas. The little evidence that is given in the answer clearly points to `defernumbers`. If that does not help, please edit your question with a full MWE and it will be reopened quite soon.