# How to sort references which are grouped in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I wanted to write the bibliography I used for my master thesis. I grouped the references I used based on their type but my problem is that the references are not sorted.

My .bib file is this

```
%The studies

@misc{study1,
title={The economic effects of the coronavirus around the world},
url={https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/02/coronavirus-economic-effects-global-economy-trade-travel/},
journal={World Economic Forum}, author={Hutt, Rosamond}, year={2020}, month={Feb}}

@misc{study2,
place={Brussels},
title={The impact of the COVID-19 crisis on poverty and social exclusion in Bulgaria},
institution={ESPN},
author={Bogdanov, George},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://ec.europa.eu/social/BlobServlet?docId=22934&langId=en}}}

@misc{study3,
title={The Covid-19 recession in France: The trough is behind us, but let’s stay vigilant},
url={https://cepr.org/voxeu/columns/covid-19-recession-france-trough-behind-us-lets-stay-vigilant},
journal={CEPR}, author={Ferrara, Laurent and Mignon, Valerie},
year={2021},
month={Nov}}

@misc{study4,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.5\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10662618/3-01042020-AP-EN.pdf/be3d73ee-6715-824b-2c23-f0512f12bdc6?t=1585657691000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020}}

@misc{study5,
title={Online dashboard and data analysis approach for assessing COVID-19 case and death data},
author={Florez, Hector and Singh, Sweta},
journal={F1000Research},
volume={9},year={2020},
publisher={Faculty of 1000 Ltd},
note ={\url{https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7450472/}}}

@misc{study6,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.3\% EU at 6.6\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10294960/3-03062020-AP-EN.pdf/b823ec2b-91af-9b2a-a61c-0d19e30138ef?t=1591123422000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Jun}}

@misc{study7,
title={Euro area unemployment at 7.9\%},
url={https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/10568643/3-01092020-BP-EN.pdf/39668e66-2fd4-4ec0-9fd4-4d7c99306c98?t=1598882965000},
author={Eurostat},
year={2020},
month={Sep}}

@misc{study8,
title={Assessing the impact of COVID-19 on Africa’s economic development},
author={Gondwe, Grace},
booktitle={United Nations Conference on Trade and Development},volume={3},
year={2020},
note = {\url{https://unctad.org/system/files/official-document/aldcmisc2020d3_en.pdf}}}

@misc{study9,
title = {Analyzing COVID-19 pandemic for unequal distribution of tests,identified cases, deaths,
and fatality rates in the top 18 countries},
journal = {Diabetes & Metabolic Syndrome: Clinical Research & Reviews},
volume = {14},
number = {5},
pages = {953-961},
year = {2020},
issn = {1871-4021},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dsx.2020.06.051},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1871402120302204},
author = {Shahbaz A. Shams and Abid Haleem and Mohd Javaid},
keywords = {Country-wise analysis, COVID-19, Life expectancy: Pandemic}}

%The R packages

@manual{package1,
title={Ggplot2 : Elegant Graphics For Data Analysis}, ISBN={9783319242750},
publisher={Cham, Schweiz] Springer},
author={Wickham, Hadley and Sievert, Carson and Springer},
year={2016},
note = {\url{https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org}}}

@manual{package2,
title = {readr: Read Rectangular Text Data},
author = {Hadley Wickham and Jim Hester and Jennifer Bryan},
year = {2022},
note = {\url{https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=readr}},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=readr}}

@manual{package3,
title = {dplyr: A Grammar of Data Manipulation},
author = {Hadley Wickham and Romain François and Lionel Henry and Kirill Müller},
year = {2022},
note = {R package version 1.0.10},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dplyr}}

@Manual{package4,
title = {randomcoloR: Generate Attractive Random Colors},
author = {Ron Ammar},
year = {2019},
note = {R package version 1.1.0.1},
url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=randomcoloR}}

%Sources for theory

@book{book1,
title={Πολυμεταβλητή Στατιστική Ανάλυση},
ISBN={9603515949}, publisher={Εκδόσεις Σταμούλη},
author={Καρλής, Δημήτρης},
year={2005},
note = {\url{https://www.stamoulis.gr/\%CE\%A0\%CE\%BF\%CE\%BB\%CF\%85\%CE\%BC\%CE\%B5\%CF\%84\%CE\%B1\%CE\%B2\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B7\%CF\%84\%CE\%AE-\%CE\%A3\%CF\%84\%CE\%B1\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CF\%83\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE-\%CE\%91\%CE\%BD\%CE\%AC\%CE\%BB\%CF\%85\%CF\%83\%CE\%B7_p-406955.aspx}}}

@book{book2,
title={Ανάλυση Συστάδων},
url={https://repository.kallipos.gr/handle/11419/1238},
publisher={Kallipos, Open Academic Editions},
author={Κύρκος, Ευστάθιος},
year={2015}}

%I used some master theses as sources for some theory

@mastersthesis{msc3,
title = {Διαχωριστική Ανάλυση και εφαρμογές},
url = {https://dspace.lib.ntua.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/5414/\%CE\%B9\%CF\%89\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BD\%CE\%BD\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B4\%CE\%BF\%CF\%85\%CE\%BA_\%CE\%B4\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%CF\%87\%CF\%89\%CF\%81\%CE\%B9\%CF\%83\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE.pdf?sequence=3},
author = {Κυριακή Ι. Ιωαννίδου},
year = {2011},
school = {Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών και Φυσικών Επιστημών}}

@book{book4,
author = {Κ. Φωκιανός και Χ. Χαραλάμπους},
title = {Ανάλυση Κατά Συστάδες στην R 1 21.1 Εισαγωγή},
url = {http://www.mas.ucy.ac.cy/~fokianos/GreekRbook/clustering.pdf},
urldate = {2022-12-18},
note = {\url{http://www.mas.ucy.ac.cy/~fokianos/GreekRbook/clustering.pdf}}
}

@mastersthesis{msc5,
author = {Στρατινάκης, Νικόλαος},
title = {Εφαρμοσμένη Ανάλυση Συστάδων },
url = {https://dias.library.tuc.gr/view/manf/79057},
school = {Πολυτεχνείο Κρήτης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένα Μαθηματικά για μηχανικούς},
year = {2018}}

@mastersthesis{msc6,
author = {Καλλιόπη, Παπούλια},
title = {Μέθοδοι Πολυμεταβλητής Ανάλυσης Επιχειρηματικών Δεδομένων},
school = {Πανεπιστήμιο Πειραιώς Τμήμα Στατιστικής και Ασφαλιστικής Επιστήμης Π.Μ.Σ Εφαρμοσμένη Στατιστική},
url = {https://dione.lib.unipi.gr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/unipi/12905/\%CE\%94\%CE\%B9\%CF\%80\%CE\%BB\%CF\%89\%CE\%BC\%CE\%B1\%CF\%84\%CE\%B9\%CE\%BA\%CE\%AE\%20\%CE\%95\%CF\%81\%CE\%B3\%CE\%B1\%CF\%83\%CE\%AF\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%A0\%CE\%B1\%CF\%80\%CE\%BF\%CF\%8D\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CE\%B1\%20\%CE\%9A\%CE\%B1\%CE\%BB\%CE\%BB\%CE\%B9\%CF\%8C\%CF\%80\%CE\%B7-MES18020.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y},
year = {2020}}

%Data source

@online{dataset,
title = {Our World in Data},
url = {https://github.com/owid},
organization = {GitHub}}
```

I wanted to group my references based on their type (books, packages, master theses etc.) so I wroted this .tex file

```
\documentclass[inscr,ack,preface]{dithesis}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} %my .bib file is called references.bib

\begin{document}

%My document

% manually include the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{references}
% include it also in ToC (do sth on your own)
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία} %Βιβλιογραφία is the name of the chapter in Greek

\chapter*{\bibname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax % Disable page breaks within this group
\printbibliography[type=misc, title={Μελέτες}] %for the studies
\printbibliography[type=online, title={Σύνολο δεδομένων}] %for the data source
\printbibliography[type=book, title={Βιβλία}] %for the books
\printbibliography[type=manual, title={Πακέτα στην R}] %for the packages in R programming languages
\printbibliography[type=thesis, title={Διπλωματικές Εργασίες}] %for master theses
\endgroup

%\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

The output is presented in the following pictures [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZLMO.png) [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpiqL.png). As you can see in these pictures the references are grouped but not sorted. What do you think I should do in order to keep them grouped and also sorted. I have searched a lot and I haven't found something useful yet. Can you provide me the LaTeX code?

Comment: Hi @Billy. In your images it seems that the entries are sorted by there reference number. What kind of sorting do you want? After year, authors lastname...?

Comment: Hi @lukeflo, I want the references of the group "Μελέτες" to be presented as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, the reference of the group "Σύνολο δεδομένων" to be presented as 10, the references of the group "Βιβλία" to be presented as 11,12, the references of the group "Πακέτα στην R" to be presented as 13,14,15,16, the references of the group "Διπλωματικές Εργασίες" to be presented as 17,18,19. If I have this order then when you go to the bibliography you will see the references with the order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` line with `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the edit.