# Change references sorting in different bibliography sections

Tags: biblatex

I have my bibliography organized into sections (Papers, Articles, Technical Reports, Books, Online). For example:

> Papers:
>
> [4] Paper x
>
> [12] Paper y
>
> etc
>
> Articles:
>
> [2] Article x
>
> [16] Article y
>
> etc
>
> Books:
>
> [1] Book x
>
> [7] Book y
>
> etc
>
> etc

Now the problem, as you can see, is that the references are not sorted in each section. What I would like to do is something like:

> Papers:
>
> [1] Paper x
>
> [2] Paper y
>
> etc
>
> Articles:
>
> [3] Article x
>
> [4] Article y
>
> etc
>
> Books:
>
> [5] Book x
>
> [6] Book y
>
> etc
>
> etc

Here is how I'm doing the sectioning:

```
\printbibheading
\nobibintoc

\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=inproceedings,title={Papers}]
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=article,title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=report,title={Technical Reports}]
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=book,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=inbook,title={In Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=npbbib,type=misc,title={Online}]
```

Comment: Use the option `defernumbers=true`? If that does not help, please prepare a short but fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) with which we can play around.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. \usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

Comment: See also [biblatex - Consistent numbering in split bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `defernumbers` option to `true`. That way the numbers are assigned when the lists are printed. In your case that gives continuous numbering. See also [biblatex advises defernumbers=true but details of references may be very hard to find](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332431/35864) for a more through explanation of the option (and its drawbacks in certain scenarios).

```
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Note that up to an including version 3.6 (the current version) you will get a warning `Package biblatex Warning: Setting 'defernumbers=true' recommended.` if you use a numeric setup with split bibliographies. If I understand correctly this warning is going go be dropped from 3.7 onwards following a short discussion sparked by the question linked in the answer (you'll find the links there).