# Continious numbering of the bibliography over multiple Subsections

Tags: biblatex, numbering

For my bibliography, it is demanded, that I separate books from articles but have a continuous numbering throughout the bibliography. But I'm just not able how to archive the desired formation. Here is my Tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\textwidth138mm

\begin{document}

text \cite{bookAaa} more text \cite{articleAaa}
even more text \cite{bookBbb} ...text \cite{articleBbb}

\printbibheading [title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,title={books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={articles}]

\end{document}
```

This is what I get right now:
[image: right now]

And this is what my desired formation is:
[image: desired]

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271751/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333493/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450614/35864. But as so often with  LaTeX, you kind of needed to know the answer to find these questions in the sea of similar search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With split numeric bibliographies you almost always want the option `defernumbers=true,`. That option makes sure that your entries are numbered sequentially in the order they appear in your bibliographies and not according to the global sorting (i.e. the number they would get if all entries were in the same global bibliography).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

text \cite{worman} more text \cite{sigfridsson}
even more text \cite{nussbaum} ...text \cite{aksin}

\printbibheading [title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,title={books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={articles}]

\end{document}
```

[image: Sequentially numbered bibliography.]

---

Note that `defernumbers` can be a bit tricky at times. If you switch the option on or off or there are other large bibliography-related changes in your document, the numbering can get stuck in an undesirable state. In that case just delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf`) and compile again with the sequence LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.