# Group the references in bibliography by self-defined topic

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a long LaTeX report with many references. I've been asked to group the references according to their topic. So for example, I would like the references to appear sorted by customised topics looking something like this:

> References
>
> UAV Use Cases
>
> [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450614/biblatex-biber-subbibliography-sorting-by-keywords) Lifesaving drop mechanism and ﬂotation device - hover uav.
>   https://hoveruav.com.au/
>   lifesaving-drop-mechanism-and-flotation-device-hover-uav/. (Accessed
>   on 07/08/2019).
>
> [2] Zipline. https://flyzipline.com/about/. (Accessed on 07/08/2019).
>
> Path Planning
>
> [3] L. H. Nam, L. Huang, X. J. Li, and J. F. Xu. An approach for
>   coverage path planning for uavs. In 2016 IEEE 14th International
>   Workshop on Advanced Motion Control (AMC), pages 411–416, April 2016.
>   doi: 10.1109/AMC. 2016.7496385.
>
> Communications
>
> [4] Mohammad Mozaﬀari, Walid Saad, Mehdi Bennis, Young-Han Nam, and
>   M´erouane Debbah. A tutorial on uavs for wireless networks:
>   Applications, challenges, and open problems. CoRR, abs/1803.00680,
>   2018. URL http: //arxiv.org/abs/1803.00680.
>
> [5] Lav Gupta, Raj Jain, and Gabor Vaszkun. Survey of important issues
>   in UAV communication networks. IEEE Communications Surveys and
>   Tutorials, 18(2):1123–1152, 2016. doi: 10.1109/COMST.2015.2495297. URL
>   https://doi.org/10.1109/COMST.2015.2495297.

I've seen grouping of references by document section but that's not really what I want. Is it possible to group references in this way? I guess it would require some custom tag in the `bibtex` code to label the reference to be placed in the relevant section?

EDIT:
I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450614/biblatex-biber-subbibliography-sorting-by-keywords)

Comment: with biblatex package (instead of bibtex) that's easy with keywords